# programatically position given number of edittext as boxes Android

Tags: android-edittext

I have the requirement to place multiple EditText shown as boxes (5 per row). Here is the code so far and the screenshot of what I have achieved. Can someone please help?

```
EditText[] et = new EditText[count];
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicsletters);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        et[i] = new EditText(this);
        et[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f
        ));
        //et[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
        et[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        et[i].setHint("Pos"+(i+1));

        //et[i].setWidth(40);//.layout(100,0,0,0);
        et[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangleborder);
        linearLayout.addView(et[i]);
    }
    layout.addView(linearLayout);
```

[image: image for 15 count]

The maximum number is 15 EditBoxes. After that I need to get the values entered to a String Array.

Expected output
[image: EditText boxes 5 per row]

Comment: Could you include image of your expected result? and what issues you have with current code?

Comment: The current code is giving the edittext boxes next to each other and does not have a fixed width, which I would like to achieve. Have uploaded the expected image (PaintBrush)

Answer (score 0):

You added all elements to 1 row.
To add 5 per row you need create new LinearLayout for each row.

```
private void addEditText(LinearLayout parent, int count, int maxItemInRow) {
    EditText[] et = new EditText[count];
    LinearLayout oneRowLayout = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
        if(i%maxItemInRow == 0){
            oneRowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            oneRowLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            oneRowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            oneRowLayout.setWeightSum(maxItemInRow);

            parent.addView(oneRowLayout);
        }
        et[i] = new EditText(this);
        et[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f
        ));
        //et[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
        et[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        et[i].setHint("Pos"+(i+1));

        //et[i].setWidth(40);//.layout(100,0,0,0);
        et[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangleborder);
        oneRowLayout.addView(et[i]);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
    LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
    int count = 15;
    int maxItemInRow = 5;
    addEditText(rootView,count,maxItemInRow);
```

Comment: I have switched to GridView and based on column and row counts, able to achieve my requirement. Thank you

Comment: if my answer resolves your origin problem, could you please make it as accepted?